# How to make CocoaPods use iOS SDK when validating podspec?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Is there an option to make CocoaPods use `iphoneos` SDK instead of `iphonesimulator`?

I'm trying to create a CocoaPods package with the iOS framework. I've set up a local repo, created simple podspec pointing to zipped framework on my local machine and tried to push it. I'm using Intel x86_64 MacBook and my framework only includes arm64 binaries.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name         = "MyFramework"
  spec.version      = "0.0.1"
  spec.summary      = "A short description of MyFramework."
  spec.description  = <<-DESC
  test creating podspec 
                   DESC
  spec.homepage     = "http://EXAMPLE/MyFramework"
  spec.license      = "WTFPL"
  spec.author       = "Spec Author"
  spec.platform     = :ios, "13.0"
  spec.source       = { :http => 'file:///Users/sergey/my-cocoapods-specs/MyFramework.framework.zip' }
  spec.ios.vendored_framework = "MyFramework.framework"
end
```

On pushing the podspec CocoaPods tries to validate it by creating and building Xcode project

```
-> Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
  Building with `xcodebuild`. 
  $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild clean build -workspace
  /var/folders/_p/rv1wb_yx36bbblqmbs9vk6zc0000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20230623-39252-s3fsmh-MyFramework/App.xcworkspace -scheme App -configuration Release
  CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=- -sdk iphonesimulator -destination id=16F6C838-B862-433E-95F5-1D261BF21FD5
  2023-06-23 10:34:17.741 xcodebuild[39262:37065719] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
  Command line invocation:
      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild clean build -workspace /var/folders/_p/rv1wb_yx36bbblqmbs9vk6zc0000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20230623-39252-s3fsmh-MyFramework/App.xcworkspace -scheme App -configuration Release CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=- -sdk iphonesimulator -destination id=16F6C838-B862-433E-95F5-1D261BF21FD5

  User defaults from command line:
      IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

  Build settings from command line:
      CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = -
      SDKROOT = iphonesimulator16.4
```

and fails with linker error

```
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, file '/var/folders/_p/rv1wb_yx36bbblqmbs9vk6zc0000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20230626-14275-uyh1a7-MyFramework/Pods/MyFramework/MyFramework.framework/mylibrary' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried to set SDKROOT in xcconfig section:

```
  spec.pod_target_xcconfig = {
      'SDKROOT' => 'iphoneos16.4'
  }
  spec.user_target_xcconfig = {
      'SDKROOT' => 'iphoneos16.4'
  }
```

but CocoaPods keeps putting `-sdk iphonesimulator` to `xcodebuild` invocation.

Comment: OK, I was able to proceed with `--skip-import-validation` option passed to `pod repo push`, but answers on how to specify SDK/arch are still welcome.